# C# datagridview export to reportviewer?

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, export, reportviewer

I have a form and a datagridview. I want to export datagridview to ReportViewer. How can I do that? Because I am filtering datagridview now but I cant filter reportviewer. If that is not imposibble, can you tell me How can I filter reportviewer? I use Visual Studio 2010

Thanks every one

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252125%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LocalReport Processing Mode you can do the following,

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource Rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource(DataSet.Name, SortedAndFilteredDataGridView);
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Rds);
```

Ideally this should work, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.